Add a boot or booting tag

I have a question about my Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange post: Windows boot sequence operation
My original question is about the boot operation (or boot sequence). I was surprise to not find a boot (or booting tag). Since this site is about system operation (amongst other things) isn't boot a fundamental operation?
I am just asking to create the boot (or booting) tag.

Created boot. Sorry, hadn't seen this earlier.
